# Issue with Session (PHP)

Tags: session

I'm having some problems with indexing sessions. I did a function to index the sessions that i want. I used it on a report system, to people don't report the same thing and do a mass insert on the report table. It works, it's blocking people. But, at the first time when you report (when the Session is not indexed), it show this error:
**Notice: Undefined index: SessionReport8 in C:\xampp\htdocs\sucess\reportprocess.php on line 12**

I set it to null. I echo it, and it's null, not undefined. How to solve it?

Here is the function:

```
    function indexarSession($Session)
{
    if (!isset($Session))
    {
        $Session = null;
        return $Session;
    }
    else
    {
        $Variavel = $Session;
        return $Variavel;
    }
}
```

And where it's been applied:

```
$SessionReport = $Funcoes->indexarSession($_SESSION["SessionReport" . $PostID]);

        if (!isset($SessionReport))
    {
        **DO THE INSERT*
    }
    else
    {
            **SHOW MESSAGE**
    }
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: print $_SESSION["SessionReport" . $PostID] and let us know the output

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Session in your indexarSession() function without checking if it's set.

Try,

```
if(isset($_SESSION["SessionReport" . $PostID])){
   $SessionReport = $Funcoes->indexarSession($_SESSION["SessionReport" . $PostID]);
} else {
   // Session not set.
}
```

Comment: But i'm doing this function just to avoid the conditional on the script. Just using the function and set it or not. How i should alter the function to avoid if/else on the script page?

Comment: You need to do the isset check before you pass it to the function.
To surpress the error, you could do @$_SESSION["SessionReport" . $PostID]

But this isn't good practice.

Comment: Because the @ symbol in front of a variable/function suppresses any errors that occur from/with it.

Making it hard to debug possible unexpected results in your output.